# Getting previous day's date in Unix

Tags: shell, date, solaris, unix-timestamp

I am using the following code to assign previous day's date to a variable *yesterday*:

```
yesterday=`TZ=GMT+24 date +%Y%m%d`;
echo $yesterday;
```

The value is assigned correctly when I execute the command during early morning hours.
But during night hours (around 9 PM), I am not getting the previous day date, but the same date as today.

My server is located in PDT timezeone.
I tried "TZ=PDT+24" for assigning, but got the same result.

FYI, I am using Solaris 5.10.

What can be the reason for this bizarre situation?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, when my batch is executed around midnight. I guess it depends on the value of GMT, I am in GMT+1. I was thinking to use CET rather than GMT, but I am looking for a general solution, not depending on the zone.

Answer (score 5):

I cannot do an exact test on solaris. but on linux this works for getting last day(yesterday):

```
kent$ date -d'yesterday' +%Y%m%d
20130520
```

so you just type "yesterday", you don't have to do something special with `date`. It is cool, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks @Kent. I am aware it works in Lunix, but unfortunately, it doesnt work in Solaris. 
`$ date -d 'yesterday' date: illegal option -- d 
usage: date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS] 
       date [-u] [+format]
       date -a [-]sss[.fff]`

Comment: If you are looking for a Linux solution, this works and is the easiest solution I have found anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

On Solaris simply use GNU date rather than the Solaris version. Access with `gdate` as opposed to `date`. Then you simply do

```
gdate -d'yesterday' +%Y%m%d
```

Your Solaris SysAdmin may have given you a crippled host where GNU coreutils (GNU date is part of that package) are not installed by default. Shame on him.

More info on what a Solaris host *should* look like on [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66415/solaris-default-install-user-tools/). The link has info for both Solaris 10 and Solaris 11.

Answer (score 1):

For Unix OS, this works fine for me

```
date +%Y/%m/%d --date="yesterday"
```

Comment: not in Solaris 11.3 (SunOS myserver 5.11 11.3 sun4v sparc sun4v)

Answer (score 0):

There is a special variable in date '-v' and you can add a -v -1d to retreive the previous day record. I believe it should work fine on Solaris as well. The PDT timezone might not be an issue.

so a command like date -v -1d would give you yesterday's date.

Comment: Never heard of the `-v` option. Doesn't exist on Solaris.